# Angularjs $locationChangeStart doesn't trigger

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm trying to prevent user to leave a form if he changed something in it in Angular. I've read some articles about this and found $locationChangeStart. The problem is that this method doesn't get triggered after I modify something in the form and then navigate to other page. Only the window.onbeforeunload is called.

Here is the directive:

```
.directive(
            'confirmOnExit',
            function() {
                return {
                    link : function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                        $scope
                                .$on(
                                        '$locationChangeStart',
                                        function(event, next, current) {
                                            if ($scope.addEventForm.$dirty) {
                                                if (!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                            if ($scope.addEventForm.$dirty) {
                                return "You have unsaved information!";
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };
```

Here is the form:

```
<form name="addEventForm"
            method="POST" ng-controller="formController" confirm-on-exit>
...

</form>
```

Where i am wrong?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: A fiddle or plunkr to play with would be great, I'm comparing with my code, in my case I ahve this in the controller and working fine, another thing to try, insteaad of scope, use $rootScope

Comment: make sure you don't miss the closing parenthesis after at the end.

Answer (score -1):

If you come across this, try $rootScope with **$locationChangeStart** as suggested in the comments. Or if you are using Angular UI-Router, use **$stateChangeStart**:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', warnIfUnsavedChanges);
```

**$routeChangeStart** if using ngRoute.

[Difference between $locationChangeStart, $routeChangeStart, and $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779704/difference-between-locationchangestart-routechangestart-and-statechangestar)