# ui-router events and $location events order

Tags: angularjs, events, angular-ui-router, location

I want to know which one comes first and what is the correct order of these events?

`$locationChangeStart`, `$locationChangeSuccess`, `$stateChangeStart`, `$stateChangeSuccess`

Answer (score 0):

`$locationChangeStart` and `$stateChangeStart` events will be broadcasted before a URL or state will change and `$locationChangeSuccess` or `$stateChangeSuccess` events will be called after `$locationChangeStart` or `$stateChangeStart` if your url or state gets successfully changed.

Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779704/difference-between-locationchangestart-routechangestart-and-statechangestar) post for more information about differences between `$locationChangeStart` , `$stateChangeStart`. Hope this will helpful to you.